# How do I access variables output of a scope in C++?

Tags: c++, scope

For example,

```
class GetDepth_Class {
    public:
        vector<int> positionX, positionY;
        vector<int>::iterator it;
        int getDepth();
    };

int GetDepth_Class::getDepth(){
                ......
                ......
                if (scalar[0] == 0 && scalar[1] == 0 && scalar[2] == 0) {

                    it = positionX.begin();
                    positionX.insert(it, i + 80);

                    it = positionY.begin();
                    positionY.insert(it, j + 80);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < positionX.size(); i++) {
                    cout << positionX[i] << "," << positionY[i] << endl;
                }


return EXIT_SUCCESS;//realsense depth camera module
}

    int main() {

    GetDepth_Class Obj;
    Obj.getDepth();

    //Here I would like to access the values of vector positionX and vector positionY output from GetDepth_Class::getDepth(), 
    //how should I do if I want to avoid using global variable?

}
```

I would like to access the values of vector positionX and vector positionY output from getDepth() in main(), and I want to avoid using global varible. Is there any solution for it?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `int depth = Obj.getDepth();`?

Comment: Define "access the values". Which elements? All of both vectors? Then you can provide accessors to return const-references or copies of the member variables. If you want to return them all from one function, then just return a `std::tuple` or `struct` containing all the fields of interest. Or return them from `getDepth()`, and signal error some other way, e.g. by throwing an exception, instead of returning an error code.

Comment: Like all member accesses; `Obj.positionX` and `Obj.positionY`. I think you're in need of a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thanks for your replying.  
I think I've missed some points. I am not sure if I express it in a right way. But when I used Obj.positionX in int main() function, it does not access the positionX output inside GetDepth_Class::getDepth(), it can only access the positionX defined in class GetDepth_Class. All I want to do is use the values of positionX and positionY output by getDepth() to do some calculation in main().  
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to get the two values from `getDepth()` function and access it in `main()`?

Comment: When I did like 
`GetDepth_Class Obj;
    Obj.getDepth();

    for (int i = 0; i < Obj.positionX.size(); i++) {
        cout << Obj.positionX[i] << "," << Obj.positionY[i] << endl;
    }

    //swap (clear) the elements of vector and clear the memory
    vector <int>().swap(Obj.positionX);
    vector <int>().swap(Obj.positionY);`

in the main(), it does not output any value.

Comment: Hi, Rohan Bari. Definitely right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `struct` for returning multiple values too:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// using a struct for returning multiple variables
struct Decl
{
    vector<int> posX;
    vector<int> posY;
};

class GetDepth_Class
{
    // these are private members now
    vector<int> positionX, positionY;
    vector<int>::iterator it;

public:
    Decl getDepth();
};

Decl GetDepth_Class::getDepth()
{
    Decl d;

    it = positionX.begin();
    positionX.insert(it, 80);

    it = positionY.begin();
    positionY.insert(it, 74);

    d = {positionX, positionY};

    for (int i = 0; i < positionX.size(); i++)
        cout << positionX[i] << "," << positionY[i] << endl;

    return d;
}

int main()
{

    GetDepth_Class Obj;
    Decl x = Obj.getDepth();

    for (int i = 0; i < x.posX.size(); i++)
        cout << x.posX[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < x.posY.size(); i++)
        cout << x.posY[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I know it's a little bit messy but understandable.

I had set `{positionX, positionY}` and returned it and read it in `main()` using a loop.

> **Sample Output:**

```
80,74 // printed from class function
80    // positionX from main()
74    // positionY from main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have declared all your class members as public, you can just access them directly via `Obj.positionX` etc.  Not good practice, but given your example code that is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your replying. When I used Obj.positionX in int main() function, it does not access the positionX output inside GetDepth_Class::getDepth(), it can only access the positionX defined in class GetDepth_Class.

Comment: When I did like 
`GetDepth_Class Obj;     Obj.getDepth();      for (int i = 0; i < Obj.positionX.size(); i++) {         cout << Obj.positionX[i] << "," << Obj.positionY[i] << endl;     }      //swap (clear) the elements of vector and clear the memory     vector <int>().swap(Obj.positionX);     vector <int>().swap(Obj.positionY);` in the main(), it does not output any value.